# How to check if sql insert added anything and select got something with db class in python

Tags: python, sql, mariadb

I have [this database class](https://pastebin.com/vSV5WRf6) written for Python 2.7 and MariaDB. And I want to print a message if an insert was successful or a warning if the element doesn't exist and the insert failed. Should I modify the database class or is it alright with the return values it provides? This is my try:

```
def  insertProduct (db, name, attrName, attrValue):
    sql = 'INSERT IGNORE `product` SET ' + attrName + ' = %s WHERE `name` = %s'
    sql2 = """SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `name` = %s"""
    if  db.execute (sql, (attrValue, name))['retval']:
        print "Successfully added ('" + name + "', '" + attrName + "': " + unicode(attrValue) + ") to `product` table"
    elif not  db.execute (sql, (attrValue, name))['retval']:
        print "ERROR: Couldn't add ('" + name + "', '" + attrName + "': " + unicode(attrValue) + ") to `product` table"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if  db.execute (sql, (attrValue, name))['retval']:
        print "Successfully added ('" + name + "', '" + attrName + "': " + unicode(attrValue) + ") to `product` table"
elif not  db.execute (**sql**, (attrValue, name))['retval']:
        print "ERROR: Couldn't add ('" + name + "', '" + attrName + "': " + unicode(attrValue) + ") to `product` table"
```

Here, you are calling db.execute() in **if** block & **elif**. Suppose, if db.execute() returns *True* then it will print *successfully added string*. But db.execute returns *False* then it will go to **elif** block and again it will execute db.execute() which can return *True* or *False*, so if it is *True* which means insertion were successful but it won't print success message but if is *False* then it will print *Error: Couldn't add record*.

```
if  db.execute (sql, (attrValue, name))['retval']:
        print "Successfully added ('" + name + "', '" + attrName + "': " + unicode(attrValue) + ") to `product` table"
elif not  db.execute (**sql2**, (attrValue, name))['retval']:
        print "ERROR: Couldn't add ('" + name + "', '" + attrName + "': " + unicode(attrValue) + ") to `product` table"
```

In else block it should be **select query**

Comment: What I want to check with the second print is the case in which the value doesn't exist in the database and yet it didn't insert it. If it didn't insert it because it was there already then I don't want to print anything. And know I've seen that my code should have a `sql2` instead of `sql` in the print.

Comment: @Arturo Okay so in that case your code seems okay just you need to update **elif** block as you need to execute *select* query then **sql2** should be used instead of **sql**